# React & Babel: You may need an additional loader to handle the results of these loaders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Im working on a react app made with `create-react-app`, and whenever I start the app I get this error:

```
./node_modules/scrambles/dist/esm/scrambles.js 37:39
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (37:39)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| async function getWorker() {
>   const url = outsideStrategy.url.esm ?? outsideStrategy.url.cjs;
|   const workerInstantiator = outsideStrategy.workerInstantiator.esm ?? outsideStrategy.workerInstantiator.cjs;
|   let worker;
```

Here are my dependencies in `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/node": "^15.3.0",
    "bulma": "^0.9.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "scrambles": "^0.1.13",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

Im not knowledgeable at all when it comes to `bable`, and based on the error, that seems to be a source of the issue. I have tried downgrading `react-scripts` as another post directed, but I had no luck with that. Any help is greatly appreciated; Ive been trying to fix this for hours.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue with create react app and dependencies that use nullish coalescing. See this GitHub issue for more information https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9468

One of the suggested fixes is to change your browserslist config in your package.json to this:

```
"browserslist": [
   ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
```

That may fix it for you because it’ll change how Babel is transpiling your code. It looks like it’s not transpiling any nullish coalescing because it’s supported by the browserslist you’re targeting.

Comment: This worked for me but I also needed to delete my node_modules and reinstall everything.

Comment: yeah...this worked for me also

Comment: horishet its a miracle!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Vue.js (`v2.6.11` in my case). Adding this in my `vue.config.js` was the only thing that solved it.

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        module: {
            rules: [{ test: /node_modules[\\/]@walletconnect/, loader: 'babel-loader' }],
        }
    }
  }
```