# @reach/combobox throwing error on compile

Tags: reactjs

./node_modules/@reach/combobox/dist/reach-combobox.mjs 367:43
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (367:43)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |     id,
  |     isExpanded,
  |     navigationValue: data.navigationValue ?? null,
  |     state
  |   }) : children)));

Comment: The nulish operator is supported from nodejs version >= 14 IIRC. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using Node version 16.8.0

Comment: Thank you @NirAlfasi pointing out nullish operator. Found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67543182/react-babel-you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-results-of-these

Comment: This is the known issue with Nullish Coalescing as answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67543182/react-babel-you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-results-of-these

Comment: Since you have already found the answer, can you please mark this question as duplicate? It will help others to navigate to solution. also it will disable duplicate answers on this question.